# How are the sampling in Android and iOS accelerometers/gyro implemented?

Tags: android-sensors, core-motion

Does the Android/iOS accelerometer/gyro API use a different ADC sampling rate OR mean/filtering to perform resampling?

I am trying to find out which sampling rate is best for my application and my approach is to collect data at 100 Hz and resample at different frequencies and determine which frequency is good enough for my use case.

However, the performance of this on the real application could be closer to the one on the development environment if I knew how this sampling was implemented on the Android API/ core-motion API. Is the API simply changing the ADC sampling frequency or is it implementing a interpolation or mean filtering after sampling at a higher frequency? (Note: The answers for the Android / iOS might be different, and I do not have this level of detailed knowledge on either system.)

Any links/sources are appreciated.